# って meaning in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, particle-って

I'm very new to Japanese and I'm trying to figure out the usage of 'って' in the following sentence:

> 変な事聞くけど、君　漢字**って**得意？
>   This may sound strange, but are you good at Kanji?

The only use of って I have learned thus far is to make a quotation. However, I don't understand the purpose of って in this particular sentence. Any help would be greatly appreciated!